# Python 'for loop' to parse results

Tags: python, for-loop, bioinformatics

I am a beginning python user (trying to learn for bioinformatics) and I am having difficulties in getting my final 'for loop' correct. I have used a web-based bioinformatic program to assess the subcellular localization of certain proteins (protein names and sequences contained within ORFs) and I am trying to parse the results (contained within targetp). The web-based program that I've used truncates the names of the proteins (and does not include sequences), and I would like to parse my results file such that I have the complete name and sequence of each protein in FASTA format (this entails having a '>' + the protein name on one line, and the protein sequence on the subsequent line). I think that everything is going well until the last block of code; I end up with the proper protein names, but they are all appended to the same sequence. I know that there must be something simple that I am doing wrong, but I just can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Thanks!

The ORFs file looks like this (it's FASTA, but the " shouldn't be there, only >):

">HsaNP_000700 branched chain keto acid dehydrogenase E1, alpha polypeptide 
MAVAIAAARVWRLNRGLSQAALLLLRQPGARGLARSHPPRQQQQFSSLDDKPQFPGASAEFIDKLEFIQPNVISGIPIYRVMDRQGQIINPSEDPHLPKEKVLKLYKSMTLLNTMDRILYESQRQGRISFYMTNYGEEGTHVGSAAALDNTDLVFGQYREAGVLMYRDYPLELFMAQCYGNISDLGKGRQMPVHYGCKERHFVTISSPLATQIPQAVGAAYAAKRANANRVVICYFGEGAASEGDAHAGFNFAATLECPIIFFCRNNGYAISTPTSEQYRGDGIAARGPGYGIMSIRVDGNDVFAVYNATKEARRRAVAENQPFLIEAMTYRIGHHSTSDDSSAYRSVDEVNYWDKQDHPISRLRHYLLSQGWWDEEQEKAWRKQSRRKVMEAFEQAERKPKPNPNLLFSDVYQEMPAQLRKQQESLARHLQTYGEHYPLDHFDK

">HsaNP_060914 pyruvate dehydrogenase phosphatase precursor 
MPAPTQLFFPLIRNCELSRIYGTACYCHHKHLCCSSSYIPQSRLRYTPHPAYATFCRPKENWWQYTQGRRYASTPQKFYLTPPQVNSILKANEYSFKVPEFDGKNVSSILGFDSNQLPANAPIEDRRSAATCLQTRGMLLGVFDGHAGCACSQAVSERLFYYIAVSLLPHETLLEIENAVESGRALLPILQWHKHPNDYFSKEASKLYFNSLRTYWQELIDLNTGESTDIDVKEALINAFKRLDNDISLEAQVGDPNSFLNYLVLRVAFSGATACVAHVDGVDLHVANTGDSRAMLGVQEEDGSWSAVTLSNDHNAQNERELERLKLEHPKSEAKSVVKQDRLLGLLMPFRAFGDVKFKWSIDLQKRVIESGPDQLNDNEYTKFIPPNYHTPPYLTAEPEVTYHRLRPQDKFLVLATDGLWETMHRQDVVRIVGEYLTGMHHQQPIAVGGYKVTLGQMHGLLTERRTKMSSVFEDQNAATHLIRHAVGNNEFGTVDHERLSKMLSLPEELARMYRDDITIIVVQFNSHVVGAYQNQE

The targetp file looks like this (the M is in position 57, but the formatting here throws this off):

HsaNP_000700          445          0.939  0.020  0.089   M    1
HsaNP_060914          537          0.309  0.073  0.629   _    4

The leftmost column in targetp is the identifier (part of the header line in each protein sequence above), and I want to return only entries with an 'M' (i.e., not '_') in position 57, along with the protein name from ORFs (header line).

My script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

ORFs = open('Human.MitoCarta.fasta', 'U')
targetp = open('MitoCarta_TargetP_combined.out', 'U')
report = targetp.readlines()
protfile = open('mitocarta_no_mTP.fasta','w')
protid = []
seqdict = {}

for seq in ORFs:
    seq = seq.rstrip()
    if seq[0] == '':
        continue
    if seq[0] == '>':
        name = seq[1:]
        seqdict[name] = ''
        continue

    seqdict[name] += seq

for entry in report:
    if entry.startswith('HsaNP'):
        if entry[57] != 'M':
            protid.append(entry[0:20])
            protid = [x.strip(' ') for x in protid]


nameslist = seqdict.keys()
c = 0
for i in protid:
    if i in nameslist[c]:
        protfile.write('>%s\n%s\n\n' % (nameslist[c], seqdict[name]))
        c += 1

protfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are writing nameslist[c] and seqdict[name] but you never change 'name'.  So you need to change 'name' if you want to get the different sequences. You should write:

```
protfile.write('>%s\n%s\n\n' % (nameslist[c], seqdict[nameslist[c]]))
```

That way you should get it right.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your fix gets me output, but unfortunately, I'm still not getting the correct output (obviously my mistake). In my script, all protid names are supposed to be in in nameslist names (a subset of each name, since protid names are truncated nameslist names), but many nameslist names are not in protid. When I run my script, I get output that includes names/sequences that are not in protid, but are in nameslist. Do you have any idea why this might be?

Comment: Yes, indent the protfile.write bla bla bla so that it's inside the if condition. Otherwise it runs for every i even if it doesn't fulfill the if statement.

Comment: Thanks again. I had tried that approach, but my output is only 3 sequences, whereas is should be >700. So, I only have 3 protid names fulfilling the condition, even though all protid names are derived from the names in nameslist. Is there something else I'm doing wrong that is obvious? Is there any way for me to show the files that I'm working with for better trouble shooting? Sorry for all the questions - I'm not good at this yet!

Comment: Hi, I've updated my problem in order to better illustrate what I'm trying to do. Thanks again for helping me out.

Comment: Well I looked at it a bit and you say that you want to get all the entries with an M inpos.57; whereas in your code you write: if entry[57] != 'M'. Shouldn't it be == 'M' ??

Comment: I also suggest dedenting the protip = [x.strip(' ') ...] because you are doing it every loop run, and I guess you can just do it once after the loop has run.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say I want all cases where position 57 is not 'M'. It still isn't working for me...

Comment: Try with: if 'M' not in entry: